# How do I wait for text to appear in an element?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to wait until visibility of element present based on text inside the STRONG element below? The text contained is always changing based on the trigger.

```
<div class="alert message alert-success alert-danger" style="margin-top: 5px; width: 330px; height: auto;">
  <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">x<button>
    <span>
      <strong>
        This Video Title has already been choosen - please choose a unique title that best describes the content of the video.
      </strong>
    </span>
</div>
```

I tried with this code but got an error

```
if wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//strong[contains(text(),'This Video Title has already been choosen - please choose a unique title that best describes the content of the video.']"))):
        print("Success")
    else:
        print("Failed")
```

This is what appears before text inside STRONG above

```
<div class="alert message alert-success alert-danger" style="margin-top: 5px; width: 330px; height: auto;">
  <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert">x<button>
    <span>
      <strong>
        Proccessing...
      </strong>
    </span>
</div>
```

so i try the if condition and i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Zephyr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\__main__.py", line 
39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\Zephyr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Zephyr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\Zephyr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Zephyr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "c:\Users\Zephyr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "e:\Coding Space\test.py", line 164, in <module>
    input_data()
  File "e:\Coding Space\test.py", line 105, in input_data
    if wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//strong[contains(text(), 'This Video Title has already been choosen - please choose a unique title that best describes the content of the video.')]"))):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:182:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:394:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:134:16
```

Comment: What are different examples of the text that is in the STRONG element? Are they subtle variations or completely different? How many different strings can there be? 10? 10,000? BTW, you can't use a CSS selector to locate an element by contained text, that has to be an XPath.

Comment: i added the difference with image there. the difference just the text inside STRONG element. Before text inside the first image is "Proccessing..." text. But it changed like the first image

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Comment: okay noted, will do it next time. sorry for this, still new on stackoverflow

Comment: The intention is for you to fix THIS \*and\* all future questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `ExpectedCondition` already available to do just this... wait for specified text to appear in an element, `EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(locator, expected_string)`.

You can use it like

```
expected_string = "This Video Title has already been choosen - please choose a unique title that best describes the content of the video."
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
try:
    wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//strong")), expected_string)
    print("Success")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Failed")
```

See [the docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element) for more info.

---

Alternate

```
if wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//strong[contains(text(), 'This Video Title')]"))):
        print("Success")
    else:
        print("Failed")
```

Comment: i tried to change the locator it still ends up failed.

Comment: What was the error? Are you sure the expected string is ALWAYS the same? Exactly the same? Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: it just keep printing Failed. Yes the expected string is ALWAYS the same, exactly the same. Ah sorry i cannot, u need to login for that

Comment: I had the completely wrong locator in my answer... I must have copied it from somewhere else. I've updated it to the correct locator. If this doesn't work, you'll need to check and see if the element is inside an IFRAME or shadow-root, etc.

Comment: not inside an IFRAME or shadow-root, but still printed Failed. ah im gonna search and tweak more, hopefully it will print Success

Comment: Let's back up and do something simple and make sure we aren't making a mistake. Try the alternate answer I just added. Make sure this code is not inside a `try` so we can see the full error message.

Comment: i already try with if condition and it got error

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: check my post above, i edited it and added the error

Comment: Try the code in my answer under the Alternative title.

Comment: sorry my bad, its already works. thanks for the assist